# MS Forms ComboBox not updating in VBA during run-time

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a combobox on a userform which is not updating, *unless* I put a breakpoint and step through the code, or pop a `MsgBox`, etc.

```
'MsgBox "", vbInformation
Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = groupVar
Debug.Print "After updating Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = " & _
            groupVar & ":  " & (Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = groupVar)
```

I confirm there are no events that fire after this. The form is displayed `vbModeless`, and when I display a msgbox, or if I step through the code using `F8` debugger, the `CrossVariable_Cbox.Value` updates correctly.

My `Debug.Print` statement confirm that the values match, however, if I allow this to run uninterrupted (no msgbox, no debug mode), the form displays with no value, even though the `Print` tells me that it was updated correctly.

This is of course causing that "Invalid Property Value" notification from MS Forms.

Any suggestions?

In the shot below, the value should be "insurer" and listindex of 372 or something like that. Both confirm if I debug it, but when I allow it to run uninterrupted, the box displays empty/listindex = -1, and causes the error...

[image]

Comment: Try this `Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = groupVar DoEvents`

Comment: @Santosh on a separate line, the `DoEvents` statement?  I will try that in the morning.

Comment: @Santosh partial success... my Debug statement now tells me `False` which is a step in the right direction. but it still appears as a blank.  This does avoid the initial MS Forms warning, but unless I make a selection in that combobox, I get the same warning on the next action/event.

Comment: @Santosh I put `DoEvents` on the preceding line, and it works. Thanks!!

Comment: @Santosh: Thanks! DoEvents solved my headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Santosh's suggestions, I was able to fix this.

Santosh suggests:

```
Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = groupVar
DoEvents
```

This was a partial success. My Debug statement now tells me `False`, and the ComboBox still displays a blank value. This somehow avoids the initial MS Forms warning, but unless I were to make a selection in the combobox, the next action/event would raise the warning.

I played around a bit, and put the `DoEvents` ahead of the ComboBox assignment:

```
DoEvents
Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = groupVar

Debug.Print "After updating Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = " & _
            groupVar & ":  " & (Group_Form.CrossVariable_Cbox = groupVar)
```

Now, my debug statement tells me `True`, *and* most importantly, the form displays the correct value in the ComboBox.